# adding text box on top of gwt java

Tags: java, gwt

I am currently working on a school project where we are creating a GWT web application which uses a GeoChart widget to display information about the servers we have crawled. Simply put, I would wish to create a text box on top of our GeoChart widget which shows an interactive world map that takes up the whole screen right now to input information. I have searched quite extensively but I have been unable to come up with an answer.

Here is the code as follows:

```
@Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {

        dataReader = (DataReaderAsync) GWT.create(DataReader.class);

        RootLayoutPanel.get().add(getSimpleLayoutPanel());

        // Create the API Loader
        ChartLoader chartLoader = new ChartLoader(ChartPackage.CORECHART);
        chartLoader.loadApi(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                getSimpleLayoutPanel().setWidget(getGeoChart());
                drawGeoChart();
            }
        });
    }
```

As GeoChart is a widget, it is wrapped under(i am not sure if this is the right word) a SimpleLayoutPanel right now which will display it into a full screen. As stated above, I would wish to include text above the geoChart. From my understanding, I would need to create another widget containing my text and add both the GeoChart widget and the text box widget into it. What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: I would go with [DockLayoutPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockLayoutPanel.html) (or [DockPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockPanel.html)), add a TextBox to the `north` dock and `GeoChart` to the `center` dock.

Comment: Hi, I tried to use DockLayoutPanel to add both the TextBox and the GeoChart but for some reason the GeoChart does not appear. I have found a solution which I have answered below. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear all thanks for answering my question. To rectify this problem, I have made use of the custom widget API within GWT(known as Composite). Here's the code as below:

```
private static class CombinedWidget extends Composite {

      public CombinedWidget() {
         // place the check above the text box using a vertical panel.
         VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
         DockLayoutPanel dPanel = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.EM);
         panel.setSpacing(13);
         panel.add(nameProject);
         nameProject.setStyleName("gwt-Group-Label");
         panel.add(className);
         panel.add(nameKs);
         panel.add(nameEsmond);
         panel.add(nameBowen);
         panel.add(nameAaron);
         dPanel.addWest(panel, 13);
         dPanel.add(getGeoChart());

         // all composites must call initWidget() in their constructors.
         initWidget(dPanel);

         setWidth("100%");

      }
```

Actually I sort of changed from the original idea. Instead of putting it on the very top, I attached the labels into a VerticalPanel and then created a CombinedWidget(custom widget) which adds both a VerticalPanel and DockLayoutPanel together. I then added the VerticalPanel(containing all the labels) and the GeoChart into the DockLayoutPanel.

This solved my problem of displaying both the labels and the GeoChart on the same page(as originally i added it into a VerticalPanel but it would not work as the app would not read the GeoChart due to the VerticalPanel being overlayed on top of the GeoChart).

If you guys want a picture of my app to visualise, please say so!

Answer (score 0):

I believe [DialogBox](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DialogBox.html) could solve your problem. People usually program the DialogBox in a way that it only pops up into display when certain event is triggered and disappears after user finishes some operation. In your particular case, you can simply make the DialogBox shows up from the beginning and never disappears. And the best part of it: you don't need to add the DialogBox widget to the geoChart widget. Calling dialogBox.center() or dialogBox.show() will do the magic for you.

Here is the sample code.

```
@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {

    dataReader = (DataReaderAsync) GWT.create(DataReader.class);

    RootLayoutPanel.get().add(getSimpleLayoutPanel());

    // Create the API Loader
    ChartLoader chartLoader = new ChartLoader(ChartPackage.CORECHART);
    chartLoader.loadApi(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            getSimpleLayoutPanel().setWidget(getGeoChart());
            drawGeoChart();
        }
    });

    // NOTE: the first argument 'false' makes sure that this dialog box
    // will not disappear when user clicks outside of it
    // NOTE: the second argument 'false' makes sure that mouse and keyboard
    // events outside of the dialog box will NOT be ignored
    DialogBox dialogBox = new DialogBox(false, false);
    DialogBox.setText("Demo");

    HorizontalPanel panel = new HorizontalPanel();
    panel.setSpacing(5);

    InlineLabel labelOfTextBox = new InlineLabel("Label");
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();

    panel.add(labelOfTextBox);
    panel.add(textBox);

    dialogBox.setWidget(panel);

    // show up in the center
    dialogBox.center();

}
```

Comment: I was contemplating the use of a DialogBox but as my TextBox was only meant to show information(like the group project name and our group name), I did not want to use a DialogBox as i felt that would be a bit unneccessary. Instead, I made a custom widget to accommodate adding text into it. See my solution below.